# AVAudioEngine sound recording changes tonality

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I have few `AVAudioPlayerNode`s for each sound user can play. Each player node is connected to its own `AVAudioMixerNode` to change volume. All of these mixers are connected to one `AVAudioMixerNode` (I named it `soundsMixerNode`) which is connected to the engine's `mainMixerNode`. User can record these sounds and then play the result record via `AVAudioPlayer`. The problem is that this record has a shifted tonality. Like if I used a pitch effect. And I get this result only on devices, simulators works good. Maybe the problem is in `AVAudioSession` categories or modes? Or maybe I have problems with `AVAudioFormat` or setting? I don't understand.
Here's my audio graph:

```
PlayerNode1 – MixerNode1
                        \
...                      soundsMixerNode – self.engine.mainMixerNode
                        /
PlayerNodeN – MixerNodeN
```

Here's my session setup:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setPreferredIOBufferDuration:128.0/audioSession.sampleRate error:NULL];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
              withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker
                    error:&error];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];
```

Here's my recording `AVAudioFile` setup:

```
NSDictionary* recordSettings = [self.engine.outputNode inputFormatForBus:0].settings;
NSError* error = nil;
self.fileForRecording = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForWriting:url
                                                   settings:recordSettings
                                                      error:&error];
```

And recording code:

```
AVAudioFormat* recordingFormat = [self.soundsMixerNode outputFormatForBus:0];
if (recordingFormat.sampleRate > 0) {
    typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.soundsMixerNode installTapOnBus:0
                               bufferSize:1024
                                   format:recordingFormat
                                    block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer * _Nonnull buffer, AVAudioTime * _Nonnull when) {
                                        NSError* error;
                                       [weakSelf.fileForRecording writeFromBuffer:buffer error:&error];
                                    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the record format. In `AVAudioFile` setup I used `[self.engine.outputNode inputFormatForBus:0].settings`, so I took an input format from my engine outputNode. But when installing tap on bus I used `[self.soundsMixerNode outputFormatForBus:0]`. These two formats are not equal. They have different sample rates. So I got a pitch in a result file.
I need to use one format both in record file setup and in `installTapOnBus:bufferSize:format:block:`. In my case I need to use outputFormat of my `self.soundsMixerNode`.